# How to browse IIS Application Pool directly from cmd?

Tags: iis, application-pool

I'm using a script to automatically recycle an App Pool.

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:AppPool
```

This App Pool was created for a Default Web Site which contains an application called "Application" that I want to browse from command line.

[image]

Is it possible or do I have to manually press "browse" whenever I want to launch the web site?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/778059/command-to-display-on-which-application-pool-the-specific-website-is-running

Comment: First, you cannot "browse" an application pool, but sites/apps/virtual directories. Second, as a site can have multiple bindings, it can be browsed via multiple links. https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Thus, there cannot be a simple command to achieve what you wanted.